# jquery - select li inside a ul that is inside ul

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I have this:

```
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Hello world</a></li>
                <li><a>hi</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a>hi</a></li>
   </ul>
```

And i need to select a li that is in the second ul (the one that has the words 'Hello world', for example.)

How do i do that with jQuery?

I tried this:

```
$('ul li:eq(1) li:eq(1)').doSomthing();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward:

```
ul ul li
```

This doesn't check for immediate nesting though; the second `ul` in the selector could very well be more deeply nested. You can restrict this by using `>`:

```
ul > li > ul > li
```

To grab only the first `li`, it might look something like this:

```
​$("ul > li > ul > li:first").css("background", "red");​​​​​​​​​​
```

The approach you attempted, using the `:eq` pseudo-selector, would have looked more like this:

```
​$("li:eq(0) li:eq(0)").css("background", "red");​​​​​​​​​​
```

Remember that index is zero-based, so the first item is always index 0.

Comment: Thank you. what I need is to add something to the a tag in one of the li's doesnt have to be the first one. see my update.

Comment: @Ovi Using the `:eq` selector will permit you to grab any arbitrary `li` element, and therefore target the `a` element within.

Answer (score 0):

The savest is to use the direct child selector [`>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

```
$("ul > li > ul")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this it will work as you wish
```

> $('ul li>ul li:eq(0)').css('border','1px solid red');